# web.config rewrite rule to update query string value in url

Tags: url-rewriting

We have a requirement to rediect the URL from https:/my.original.domain.com/quickLinks/forms/formdetail?ID={**XXXX**}&FormTemplateID={**YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY**}&FormItemID={**ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ-ZZZZ**}

to

https:/my.original.domain.com/quickLinks/forms/formdetail?ID={**AAAA**}&FormTemplateID={**BBBB-BBBBB-BBBBB-BBBB**}&FormItemID={**CCCC-CCCCC-CCCCC-CCCCC**}

The catch here is that we only have to change the query string value. We need the rewrite URL for this to work in web.config for the dot net application. We don't have to write any code for this.